# Uso do preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Com este código consigo bloquear caracteres especiais no meu `input`, porém quero que ele ainda aceite `.`, `-` e `_` como proceder?

```
elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z A-Z0-9]+$/', $username)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'login'     => false,
        'message' => 'Existem caracteres especiais no seu nome de usuário, se estiver utilizando <strong>@</strong>, remova-o.'
    ));
}
```

Comment: Adicione eles na lista (o que conteúdo que está entre os colchetes).

Comment: @rray [a-z A-Z0-9 . - _]  assim ?

Comment: Sem espaço: `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`

Comment: Só uma dúvida, isso também fará bloquear caso usuário tente logar com email ?

Comment: Só vai permitir os caracteres que estão na lista, se colocar uma `@` vai 'bloquear' e executar o `echo` e `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar esta expressão:

```
/^[\w-.@]+$/
```

Só irá retornar `true` se o `$username` tiver:

`\w` Caractere alfa-numérico. Letras (maiúsculas e minúsculas), números e _ (underline)

`-` Hífen

`.` Ponto

`@` Arroba

Qualquer caractere diferente dos listados acima, o `preg_match` será `false`.

Veja no **[Ideone](https://ideone.com/kKgllI)**.

Comment: E funcionou mesmo, obrigado @DvD